# How to mention array of object in hasura graphql action type?

Tags: graphql, hasura

How to define the Action type in Hasura graphql(console) for below given API response?

```json
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "Jordan Smith",
            "id": 101,
            "location": "Florida",            
            "speciality_id": 214
        },
        {
            "name": "Cathy Morphy",
            "id": 104,
            "location": "london",
            "speciality_id": 214
        }
    ],
    "count": 2 }
```

Comment: if your action’s response is actually related to existing objects in the schema. so, u can simply return the id from the action-response and create a relationship with that id. If not, tell us a bit about your table structures

Comment: type SearchDoctorsOutput {
  doctor : json
  count : Int
}

type Query {
  search_doctor (
    speciality_id: Int
    search: String
    limit: Int
    offset: Int
  ): SearchDoctorsOutput
}
type SearchDoctorsOutput {
  doctor : json
  count : Int
}

Can we mention like this

Comment: I don't think you can nest an object type (doctor) in the Output type. I don't think that works

Comment: Any other options are there

Answer (score 1):

If you have control over what's in your API response, and can change it to just return an array of objects (what's inside `data`), then something like this should work:

```
type Query {
  doctors(specialty_id: Int, search: String, limit: Int, offset: Int): [Doctor]
}

type Doctor {
  name: String
  id: Int
  location: String
  specialty_id: Int
}
```

If you don't have control over the API response, you'll need another layer (e.g. a serverless function or another server endpoint to request the data and transform the response into the format Hasura Actions can handle).

See also:

- https://github.com/hasura/graphql-engine/issues/4806
- https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/actions/types/index.html#custom-graphql-types